# How to insert 5 million records in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am here trying to insert 5 million documents in MongoDB and it is taking too much of time. Please suggest me a more efficient way. I have here posted db structure and related query (code). Please have a look at it and point out improvements that can be done to speed up the insertion.

DB structure:

```
    { 
        "_id" : {
            "msisdn" : "919899587091", 
            "op" : "idea", 
            "eid" : "547c0a0ccbbc64ce2b773488", 
            "cid" : "547c0a8ecbbc64cf2b773488", 
            "d" : ISODate("2015-05-26T04:30:00.000+0000")
        }, 
        "value" : {
            "unq" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ut" : "NNN"
        }
    }
```

Up to 5 million.

I am using aggregate as given below:

```
    var v = db.collection(collectionname).aggregate([{$match:{'@timestamp':             {'$gte':new Date(starttime), '$lt':new Date(endtime)},'eid':{$ne:'-'},ut:{$ne:'-'}}},
        {$project:{'msisdn':"$msisdn",'op':'$op','eid':'$eid','cid':'$cid','ut':'$ut','mi':{'$millisecond':'$@tim`enter code here`estamp'},'m':{'$minute':'$@timestamp'},'s':{'$second':'$@timestamp'},d:'$@timestamp'}},
        {$project:{'msisdn':"$msisdn",'op':'$op','eid':'$eid','cid':'$cid','ut':'$ut','d':{'$subtract':['$d',{'$add':[{'$multiply':['$m',60,1000]},{'$multiply':['$s',1000]},'$mi',1800000]}]}}},
        {$group : {'_id' : {'msisdn':"$msisdn",'op':'$op','eid':'$eid','cid':'$cid','d':'$d'},'unq':{$sum:1},'uts':{$addToSet:'$ut'}}},
        {$project:{'_id':'$_id','value':{'unq':'$unq',
      'ut':{ $cond: {if: {$setIsSubset:[['NNN'],'$uts']} ,then: 'NNN',
         else: { $cond: {if: {$setIsSubset:[['RNN'],'$uts']} ,then: 'RNN',
           else:{ $cond: {if: {$setIsSubset:[['RRN'],'$uts']} ,then: 'RRN',else:'RRR'}}
                }}
          }}} }
        }],{ allowDiskUse: true, cursor: {batchSize: 1000}});

    var bulk = db.collection(outcollectionname).initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    v.on('data', function(data){ 
            bulk.insert(data);  
        });

    v.on('end', function(){ 
    bulk.execute(function(err, result) {

            });
        });
```

Comment: Perhaps try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg [1e5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh). It may not be your dialect of English, but it is English.

Comment: @200_success English, perhaps so. But hardly widely known at all [outside of India]. We should stick to units common throughout all English dialects. I'm refraining from calling that number 500-man too... ;)

Comment: @200_success Well, I thought the idea was to make sure as many people as possible can understand a question to maximize the number of people who can answer. But I'll take it for granted and will try to use Cockney for my answers from now on... ;)

Comment: @Vikash What exactly is "too much time"? Are we talking seconds? Minutes? Hours? On what kind of system and hardware?

Answer (score 3):

I this you are doing manually what the $out stage of the aggregation pipeline is for.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

It stores the results into another collection.

This avoids to copy the object into the nodejs context and copy it back into mongodb.

Comment: I have such type of requirement that on db selection and another db paste.Kindly suggest me better approach.

Comment: You can sill use $out, and then use cloneCollection, to avoid data being copied in the node context. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/

Comment: Thanks for reply,I want to merge result every one hour.Is it possible? Kindly suggest me.

Comment: can we paste result one db from another db?

Comment: For what concerns schedules I think that a cronjob will do the work. What do you mean by "paste"?

Comment: copy from one db to another db.

Comment: can we copy result one db from another db?